# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in web application with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, intellij-idea, web-applications

I'm new to j2ee and developing a web application with java using hibernate framework for database stuff ....
When I try to access database in a stand alone class that runs on no web server and just run as a normal application ,I didn't get any exception based on ClassNotFoundException but when I try to access database in my servlet class I get many of these exceptions:

- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
  org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager

I've installed hibernate library with my IDE(IntelliJ).
I'm using java 1.8 and Tomcat9.0.0.M4 as a web server and hibernate 4.2.2

My database class :

```
public class LoginService {
    public LoginService(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("some errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
        }
        System.out.println("log1");

    }

    public boolean canLogin(String username, String password){
        SessionFactory factory;
        try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure("/net/mohtadin/config/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable ex){
            System.err.println("Failed to connect to database");
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "FROM User U where U.userName = :username";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("username",username);
            List employees = query.list();
            for (Iterator iterator =
                 employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                User user = (User) iterator.next();
                if (password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                    return true;
                    // TODO add some stuff for checking the privileges of the user
                }
            }
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

my servlet class:

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
        if (loginService.canLogin(username,password)){
            // Redirect to an other page
        }else {
            // Show some message to the user that can not login
        }
}
```

**PS:** : When I try to access my database with JDBC in my servlet i get no exception...
Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

`org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager` resides in

```
org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:<your-version>
```

Just make sure you have the jar named 'hibernate-commons-annotations' among dependencies and you should be fine.

Comment: Yep .... This gonna work for me ... I must copy this library file to the lib folder of my web server .... tnx a lot